# bokeh server subdirectories in URL

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and I'm trying to run multiple apps in one directory, like the demo site:

1. http://demo.bokeh.org/movies
2. http://demo.bokeh.org/selection_histogram
3. http://demo.bokeh.org/weather

I tried

```
cd /var/www/html/visualization/bokeh_apps/
bokeh serve --show myapp --port 5100 --host 127.0.0.1:80/visualization/bokeh_apps/
```

but it returned "invalid port in host value". When I run locally in Python `bokeh serve --show myapp`, the address is like "localhost:5006/myapp" and doesn't show any structure. Is there some trick to do this? I searched but didn't find anything. Thanks a lot!

P.S. I'm running Redhat 6.4 and Apache. My supervisor won't switch to Nignx as the web site has lots of parts other than visualization.

Comment: More information is needed. E.g. are you using Apache as a reverse proxy? Have you configured it to forward websockets? I'd suggest you stop by the Bokeh mailing list, it's alot easier to have extended conversations there (SO fo;ks get angry if you don't "answer" questions in a particular way)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! I read your answer on my other question too. I'm trying to put visual projects on our website so it's not for local use only. I'm running mainly a Wordpress blog and some static HTML pages and I don't think any reverse proxy is involved. Thanks for the Google group info, too!

Comment: Are you running your own WP blog? I think the free hosted WP sites strip all JavaScript, which is why you would not see any plot output. I'm afraid there is nothing to do about that until or unless WP change their policies.

Comment: Yes we are using our own domain, server, IP and it's not on any host service. and also, I'm trying to output bokeh apps via Apache, as my command `cd /var/www/html/visualization/bokeh_apps/` (real directory, not page inside WP), I don't think WP is involved here.

Comment: Is the Bokeh server behind Apache? I.e., do users navigate to Apache and then requests are forwarded on? I'm not an Apache expert but if that's the case, Apache probably needs to be configured to forward websocket connections.

Comment: Hmm... I think so. That's what I thought when I read the example of Nignx setting (http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#reverse-proxying-with-nginx). I read about the web socket tunneling (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) but I still have no idea how to connect to Bokeh server. I'll try to post a thread on Google group about the details of my situation. Thanks a lot!